# Using querySelectorAll to dynamically change the value on an input

Tags: javascript, css

I have multiple color inputs (16 in total) that I'm styling by using a `div` as a wrapper. The wrapper div `color-wrapper` is essentially my color input.

```
<ul class="color-picker__list">
          <li>
            <div class="color-wrapper">
              <input id="highlight-background" type="color" value="#F7EBC6">
              <label for="highlight-background">Highlight Background</label>
            </div>
          </li>
          <li>
            <div class="color-wrapper">
              <input id="highlight-accent" type="color" value="#F7D87C">
              <label for="highlight-accent">Highlight Accent</label>
            </div>
          </li>
</ul>
```

**Intended Goal**

Each wrapper `div` should have its background color set to the value of the color input it's wrapping. When changing the input, the background color should change to the color selected.

**Current Unintended Result**

Every color input is currently black and has an initial value of `#00000`. When I change the color, nothing occurs.

**What I've attempted**

I grabbed all the inputs and `color-wrapper`'s and looped over them using a nested `forEach` so that I can iterate over both and set the background color of the `color-wrapper` to be the value of the color input.

```
const colorWrappers = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('.color-wrapper'))
const inputs = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('input[type="color"]'))

colorWrappers.forEach(wrapper => {
  inputs.forEach(input => {
    wrapper.style.backgroundColor = input.value
  })
})
```

I was only successful when selecting individual colors with `querySelector`, but I need to be able to change all 16 color inputs dynamically.

**Input and Wrapper CSS**

```
input[type="color"] {
  opacity: 0;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}


.color-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  height: 35px;
  max-width: 50px;

  border-radius: 3px;
  position: relative;
  height: 30px;
  width: 30px;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin-right: 10px;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This did the trick for me:

Get all inputs elements, loop over them, add the change event to each of them, and set its color to his parent.

Javascript:

```
var inputs = document.querySelectorAll('.color-wrapper input');
inputs.forEach(function(element){
    element.addEventListener("change", function () {
        element.parentNode.style.background = element.value;
    });
})
```

Answer (score 1):

You could listen for the `change` event on an element which wraps the `input` elements. In the example below I've used a `form` element to listen on.

Whenever a user changes the color on an `input` the function in the `change` listener will be fired. It then gets the `value` from the `input` that has been used and then uses that `value` to set the background-color on the `.color-wrapper` element.

This way you can add as many color pickers that you want without having to modify your JS.

```js
const form = document.querySelector('.js-color-form');
form.addEventListener('change', function(event) {
  const wrapper = event.target.parentElement;
  const value = event.target.value;
  wrapper.style.backgroundColor = value;
});
```

```html
<form class="color-picker__form js-color-form">
  <ul class="color-picker__list">
    <li>
      <div class="color-wrapper">
        <input id="highlight-background" type="color" value="#F7EBC6">
        <label for="highlight-background">Highlight Background</label>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="color-wrapper">
        <input id="highlight-accent" type="color" value="#F7D87C">
        <label for="highlight-accent">Highlight Accent</label>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</form>
```